# working with bitwise C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, scanf

For this part I actually just need to scanf a value into a variable and then put it into an equation to spit out a number.

```
Analogue input (-5V to 5V):
1
e is -1073750280
```

the code:

```
printf("Analogue input (-5V -5V):\n");
scanf("%d",e);
printf("e is: %d \n", e);
```

The number that e prints out as changes every time I run the program. I figure it has to do with memory but I cannot figure out what.

these are the variable declarations:

```
uint16_t *pointer;
int e,d,i;
```

Comment: Why would that be necessary?

Comment: You have to tell `scanf` where to store the value it reads. As written, you just tell it the existing value of the variable which is no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C passes all of its function parameters by *value*, not by *reference.* That means functions cannot modify their parameters directly:

```
void NoChange(int i) {
  printf("Before: %d\n", i);
  i = 10;  // Changes only the local copy of the variable.
  printf("After: %d\n", i);
}
main() {
  int n = 1;
  printf("Start: %d\n", n);
  NoChange(n);
  printf("End: %d\n", n);
}
```

Output:

```
Start: 1
Before: 1
After: 10
End: 1
```

If you want a function to change the contents of a variable, you need to pass its address. Then the function can modify the data at that address, which effectively modifies the variable:

```
void Change(int *i) {
  printf("Before: %d\n", *i);
  *i = 10;  // Changes the memory that i points to.
  printf("After: %d\n", *i);
}
main() {
  int n = 1;
  printf("Start: %d\n", n);
  Change(n);
  printf("End: %d\n", n);
}
```

Output:

```
Start: 1
Before: 1
After: 10
End: 10
```

So in order for the `scanf()` function to store data in a variable, you need to pass it the *address* of that variable, like this:

```
int e;
scanf("%d", &e);
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't going to go that in-depth but now I feel I should have. +1

Comment: Yes, fixed and commented. Thank you!

Comment: Been using C++ so much I completely forgot about & with scanf.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &e);` is the correct answer as others have pointed out. The `scanf` function needs a **pointer** to where you want it to store the data, otherwise it doesn't know where your variable is.

Since `scanf` was expecting a pointer it converted the uninitialized value stored inside `e` to a pointer and stored the result there. This is *undefined behaviour*, a phrase you will see in the C/C++ section a lot, and you shouldn't do it.

Also, since `scanf` did nothing to your variable, `printf` was printing the uninitialized value of `e`, which is why you were getting the unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&e);
```

You are missing &.

Comment: That did it. Haven't used C in several years so I forget some of the syntax.

Comment: @user3341518 If this answer has fixed it for you could you please mark it as an accepted answer? It is important to highlight what has helped you solve your problem so that others who might be having the same issue can quickly figure out what to do.